# Why I am I getting 403 - forbidden

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I was working on Spring Boot Security project and I did the authentication on some endpoints to prevent from access from USERS and granted the authority to ADMIN when ever I hit this URL: [admin/users](http://localhost:8080/admin/users). I got the login page I put the credentials and instead of returning the actual content it returns:

> type=Forbidden, status=403

Here is my SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // inject spring user details interface
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**" , "/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

**Admin users controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("admin/users")
public class UserController {
    //
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

   //  get all users
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    // test
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String message() {
        return "secured end point";
    }

    //create new users
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping
    public User registerUser(@RequestBody  User user){
        
        String password = user.getPassword();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**userDetail:**

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1256711395932122675L;
    private User user;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

**userDetailsService:**

```
[![@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
      CustomUserDetail userDetail = null;

      if(user != null) {
        userDetail = new CustomUserDetail();
        userDetail.setUser(user);
      }
      else {
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not exist with username " + username);
      }
        System.out.println("user details" + userDetail);
        return  userDetail;

    }
}][2]][2]
```

Comment: What is the name of your authority? `ADMIN` or `ROLE_ADMIN` if it is the ifrst use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Comment: here is my GrandAuthority

return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, what is it in the database. `ADMIN` or `ROLE_ADMIN`. If you are again appending `ROLE_` it will end up with `ROLE_ROLE_ADMIN` which isn't correct either.

Comment: oh ok in the database ii have two roles , ADMIN and USER

Comment: Then it should work, so either the code isn't doing what you think it is doing, or you roles aren't what you think they are.

Comment: Have you enabled debug logs and checked what they are telling you? Du ls learn how to debug your application

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks man i figured it out and I posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by simply correcting the getAuthorities() I removed "ROLE_" in `simpleGrantedAuthority()`, extracted the return into a variable in userDetail.java and used `hasAuthority()` instead of `hasRole()`.

**The code which was getting 403 - forbidden:**

```
@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        
        return user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

**The solution:**

```
 @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream().map(role -> 
                        new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return authorities;
    }
```